# How to use an intent's result in a method

Tags: java, android, eclipse, mobile, media-player

So I am using this piece of code for a user to select a song from their phone:

```
    public void alarmcode(){
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    i.setType("audio/*");
    Intent c = Intent.createChooser(i, "Select soundfile");
    startActivityForResult(c,1);
```

This does exactly what I want. However, what i want to do next is use the MediaPlayer class to be able to play this selected song. This is a piece of code that I have written for this:

```
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp.setDataSource(???);
    mp.prepare();
    mp.start();
```

Does anyone know how to grab the memory location of this - and play it? I'm really stuck. I have been googling around for ages and can't find much to help me out. Cheers for any help :)

Comment: Have you looked at this ---> http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/musicdroid-audio-player-part-i

Answer (score 1):

check it please. hope it will work for you.

http://blog.infidian.com/2008/04/04/tutorial-custom-media-streaming-for-androids-mediaplayer/

Comment: Nah, that's not what I'm after. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

to get ringtones you can call this intent..

```
mIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(mIntent, 1);
```

and while to use the intent you can use it like this..

```
@Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {`
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != intent) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {

            Uri selectedRing = intent.getData();
    }
}}
```

Comment: Just from copy/pasting this code, I get mIntent cannot resolved as a variable. Suggestions?

Comment: I've just about got it - But I can;t seem to let it call the function.

Comment: When ever I call my media player (which is named mediaplayer1), I am asked for a string, and what ever I enter is rejected with an error :/ So basically this is my code:

        public void mediaplayer1(String selectedRing){
        //body of code;
        }

Then when I try to call mediaplayer1(); it obviously says I need a string, but none of them seem to work.